# Trivial Group Center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I often tell my students in Abstract Algebra that the center of a group 
$$\{e_G\} \subseteq Z(G) := \{ g \in G \mid ag = ga,~\forall a \in G \}\subseteq G$$ 
can be seen as a measure of how much (or little) the group $G$ is commutative – e.g., $G$ is commutative if and only if $G = Z(G)$.

On the other end of the spectrum, $G$ can be seen as very non-commutative if $Z(G) = \{e_G\}$.

**Question:** Is there a (well-known) non-commutative group whose center is trivial?

**ADDED:** Here is a more precise question: Is there a basic example I can share with my students (who only know the definition of group)?

Comment: Any non-abelian simple group has this property, because the center is a normal subgroup, So, for example, $A_5.$

Comment: The trivial group is abelian, so it is definitely not what OP meant. @MiloBrandt

Comment: Both $Z(G)$ and $[G,G]$ are very rough measures of the “commutativity” of $G$. For finite groups, you can look instead at the “commuting probability”: given two random elements, how likely are they to commute? There is some pretty math involved in that. And there are other ways to try to quantify it; see [this math.overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125501/measures-of-non-abelian-ness/).

Comment: In addition to $A_n$, $n\geq 4$; $S_n$ with $n\geq 3$, the dihedral groups of order $2q$ with $q$ odd have trivial center. If $G$ any non-nilpotent group, then there is some point at which the upper central series stabilizes short of $G$, and taking the appropriate quotient will give you a centerless group.

Comment: The smallest non-abelian group, of order 6, has a trivial center (it's already contained in other answers, as $S_3$ or dihedral($6$)).

Answer (score 3):

For any $n \ge 3$, the symmetric group $S_n$ is an example of a centerless group. Of course, any abelian centerless group must be trivial, because an abelian group is its own center.